# Python corrupts files even after separating functions and downloading new input files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Mac 10.13.6 and Python 3.7.3

I had a script that ran two functions which both read the same xlsx file and then created two new files after doing some calculations. The xlsx file created from the first function opens, but when I try to open the second file, a window pops up asking to Grant Access and then an error says the file is not valid / is corrupted. Some Googling made me realize I wasn't supposed to read and write on the same file twice, but I wanted to see if I could quickly just run the functions separately to make it work.

I tried running the second function by itself in a new .py file, but the result xlsx files are still corrupted. I even tried downloading new input files to run the function on separately, but now those files are corrupted too. As soon as I paste a brand new file into the input folder for the script to use, the input file becomes corrupted before the script is even run. What the heck did I do?

Here's a sample of my code. `function2()` would be exactly same as `function1()` just with different calculations that I omitted.

```
def function1():
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    df['filename'] = os.path.basename(file)
    newfile = '/Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/HigherEd/Other_Rankings_2020/final_ranked_cc/{}.xlsx'.format(df.filename[0].replace('_', '|').replace('.xlsx', '').replace('BC 2020', 'CC 2020'))
    df2 = pd.read_excel('/Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/HigherEd/BC_Rankings_2020/2020 data pull.xlsx', usecols='A, P:DA')
    df = pd.merge(df, df2, on='UnitID', how='left')
    df3 = pd.read_excel('/Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/HigherEd/BC_Rankings_2020/program_counts.xlsx', usecols='A, C:Z')
    df = pd.merge(df, df3, on='UnitID', how='left')

    # Some calculations go here that I omitted

    df1 = df1.sort_values(by=['FinalRank'])
    df2 = pd.read_excel(file)
    df2 = pd.merge(df2, df1[['UnitID', 'FinalRank']], on='UnitID', how='left')
    df2['list_name'] = os.path.basename(file).replace('_', '|').replace('.xlsx', '').replace('BC 2020', 'CC 2020')
    cols = df2.columns.tolist()
    cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
    df2 = df2[cols]
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by=['FinalRank'])
    with pd.ExcelWriter(newfile) as writer:
        df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Final Ranked List', index=False)
        df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Calc Results', index=False)

def function2():
    # essentially same as function1()

globbed_files = glob.glob('/Users/bgoldberg/PythonScripts/HigherEd/Other_Rankings_2020/to_be_ranked_cc/*.xlsx') 
for file in globbed_files:
    function1()
    function2()
```

Comment: maybe you downloaded corrupted files and problem is internet, not code.

Comment: Converting the input to a less vile format should help avoid the atrocities that Microsoft's products and formats innately have.

Comment: All the spreadsheets, both inputs and results, worked fine running the script with one function. But once I added the second function and ran, it started corrupting the files.

Comment: I restarted my computer and now the files aren't corrupted. I will just run the functions in separate scripts for now I guess